# Header doesn't cover entire screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the background image of my homepage (www.insaka.org), to cover the entire width of the screen, but I can't seem to figure it out. **I don't want the entire website to stretch, just the image**. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<header class="business-header">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 top-buffer">
            <h1 class="tagline">Insaka</h1>
            <h4 class="tagline">Increasing access to education for rural Zambian girls</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.business-header {
background: url("/images/Insaka poster girls.JPG") center center no-repeat scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
}

main {
  @extend .container;
  margin-top: 30px; // accommodate the navbar
}

section {
  @extend .row;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: np: change your picture name, remove any spaces and use underscores. Also, where's the `business-header` class on the html ?

Comment: you haven't posted the correct code because the html code doesn't use **.business-header** class

Answer (score 1):

Well, Lots of things is wrong with the html structure. You need a good front-end developer to get the things fixed.

The simplest solution i can provide is to apply the following styles to the main tag

```
main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See your `main` tag has `max-width`

```
main {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `height:100vh` and `width:100vw` to set container to fit in
>   screen.

vh = visual-height

vw = visual-width

**In your case use `100vw` to fit element to current screen**